# Form 1 is the textfield and Form 2 is the JTable how retrieve the value of Table in form 1 textfield

Tags: java, forms, swing, logging

Form 1 is the textfield located

```
private void tblOrgMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    

    Connection cn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rss = null;
    btnSave.setEnabled(false);
    btnUpdate.setEnabled(true);
    btnDelete.setEnabled(true);

    try {
        int row = tblOrg.getSelectedRow();
        String cell_click = (tblOrg.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_organization WHERE org_id = '" + cell_click + "'";
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_organization?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
        st = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rss = st.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rss.next()) {
            String addid = rss.getString("org_id");
            txtOrgID.setText(addid);
            String addname = rss.getString("org_name");
            txtOrgName.setText(addname);
            String adddesc = rss.getString("org_description");
            txtOrgDesc.setText(adddesc);
            String addadviser = rss.getString("org_adviser");
            txtAdviserName.setText(addadviser);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Form 2 is the Jtable

```
private void tblAdviserList2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Connection cn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rss = null;
    String ab = " ";
    try {
        int row = tblAdviserList2.getSelectedRow();
        String cell_click = (tblAdviserList2.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_adviser WHERE adviser_id = '" + cell_click + "'";
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_organization?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
        st = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rss = st.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rss.next()) {
            String addid = rss.getString("firstname").concat(ab).concat(rss.getString("middlename")).concat(ab).concat(rss.getString("lastname"));
            new FrmOrganization(addid);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this seem like a round-peg-square-hole problem to me?

Comment: I cannot retrieve the value of Jtable to another form in the txtAdvisername

Comment: Do you want the _whole_ table in the text field?

Comment: Yes Sir, I want to retireve the value of the table in the txtAviserName only in Form1 but it seems it not appear in the textfield.

Comment: The value of the table is firstname, miidlename and lastname, I concat it and when it transfer to another form it will form a complete name  in the txtAdviserName..

Comment: I would recommend doing some research into the observer pattern

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

To get the value from a particular cell:

```
Object cellValue = table.getValueAt(row, col);
```

Alternatively, you can create a `TableModel` where each row represents a person object, and add a method on that.